# Why is parent suite null when accessing a test case directly from project?

Tags: c#, tfs-sdk

I think the TFS API has a bug in it, here I'll try and demonstrate:

Using a team project object like this:

```
ITestManagementTeamProject project
```

I can get direct access to the test case like this:

```
var testCase = project.TestCases.Find(testCaseId);
```

If the test case is accessed in this way then:

```
testCase.ParentTestSuite // will always be null
```

BUT

If I access the test case from the test suite like this:

```
var testSuite = project.TestSuites.Find(testSuiteId);

         foreach (var test in testSuite.TestCases)
         {
            var check = test.ParentTestSuite; // ParentTestSuite is populated
         }
```

Is it just me, or is there a bug here?

EDIT: For clarification in both cases the same objects are being used and returned.

Comment: Seem like is lazy loading the properties asociated to the object..

Comment: If it is lazy loading is there a way to force it to load without having to traverse the collection?

Comment: If you think this is a bug please vote here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/905522/test-case-parent-suite-is-null-when-loading-from-testcases-find-method